# Avoid errors when observable is null

Tags: knockout.js

I use knockout bindings.  I have the following code:

```
<div  data-bind="with: transport()">
    <textarea data-bind="text: sender().complete()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Sometimes sender is `null` thus an error occured on this binding: `text: sender().complete()`

How to proceed with knockout to avoid errors when observable is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is what I do:

When the object Transport is initializing, I created a computed for senderSignaletic which test for the existance of a sender (=Shipper entity) on the transport then retrieve the signaletic from it:

```
transport.senderSignaletic = ko.computed(function () {
    return (transport.sender()) ? transport.sender().signaletic : '';
});
```

And when the object shipper is initializing, I created a computed for signaletic which is a concatenation of name, street, number, city, ...:

```
shipper.signaletic = ko.computed(function () {
    var name = shipper.name();
    var street = shipper.street();
    var number = shipper.number();
    var postcode = shipper.postCode();
    var city = shipper.city();

    var country = shipper.country().name();
    return name + '\n' + street + ' ' + number + '\n' + postcode + ' ' + city + ' ' + country;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  data-bind="with: transport()">
    <textarea data-bind="text: sender() ? sender().complete() : ''"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: text: sender!=null ? sender().complete() : '' should be acomputed. Also a observable cant be null, it can hold a null value but it self can never be null

Comment: @Anders Thats true, but when you call `sender()` you are accessing the value, so `sender().complete()` is `null.complete()`.